# Php Soap request param as array

Tags: php, xml, soap

XML Request :

```
<ID xsi:type="xs:string">9832457</ID>    
<BookingDetails xsi:type="soapenc:Array" soapenc:arrayType="ns1:TBookingDetail[2]">

       <item xsi:type="ns1:TBookingDetail">

            <Question xsi:type="xs:string">COMMENTS</Question>

            <Answer xsi:type="xs:string">This is where the appointment notes go</Answer>

            <ErrorCode xsi:type="xs:int">0</ErrorCode>

            <ErrorDesc xsi:type="xs:string"></ErrorDesc>

            <RequestID xsi:type="xs:string"></RequestID>

        </item>

</BookingDetails>
```

I have created soap object,

```
$client     = new SoapClient($this->wsdlurl);
```

I have one method to call , MakeRegistration() in soap request,and second param is as array. Above XML request is my XML request in SoapUi then how should i pass in my below request.

```
$newresult  = $client->MakeRegistration($id,$arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution that worked for me might be it helpful to someone,

```
   $arr = array(
                      0 => array(
                         "Question"  => "COMMENTS",
                         "Answer"    => $comment, 
                         "ErrorCode" => 0,
                         "ErrorDesc" => "",  
                         "RequestID" => ""
                   ));

    $result  = $client->MakeRegistration($id,$arr);
```